# Select data by applying group by on one field and order by other field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am facing one issue while fetching record set from my table say PostCodeDistances.

Here is the source table:

```
SourceId | PostCode  |  Distance
-------- | ----------|  ---------
   1     |    200    |   4000
   1     |    300    |   2000
   1     |    400    |   1000
   2     |    300    |   5000
   2     |    400    |   3000
   2     |    500    |   4000
```

What I want is simply result with Ids grouped with minimum distance. So the output should be like:

```
SourceId | PostCode  |  Distance
-------- | ----------|  ---------
   1     |    400    |   1000
   2     |    400    |   3000
```

Problem seems simple but my mind stuck and may be I am not thinking solution in right way. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select top (1) with ties pcd.*
from PostCodeDistances pcd
order by row_number() over (partition by sourceId order by distance);
```

The more traditional method uses subqueries:

```
select pcd.*
from (select pcd.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sourceId order by distance) as seqnum
      from PostCodeDistances pcd
     ) pcd
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help. That is what I was looking for.